# Better way of comparing two numberic string values

Tags: java, string

I am comparing two numeric string values like below

```
String version1 = "01.00.00"
String version2 = "01.01.00"

if (version2.compareTo(version1) >= 0) { //false
}
```

but this is failing when I have

```
    String version1 = "01.99.00"
    String version2 = "01.100.00"
    if (version2.compareTo(version1) >= 0) { //true
    }
```

even though `"01.100.00"` greater than `"01.99.00"` . Any better approach compare these two string and determine if version2 is greater than version1

Comment: compareTo compares ASCII values. Java doesn't care that your string contains digits. You need to parse and compare those integers yourself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following custom `Comparator`:

```
class MyComparator implements Comparator<String> {    
    @Override
    public int compare(String s1, String s2) {  

        int compVal;   

        int s1index1 = s1.indexOf(".");
        String s1part1 = s1.substring(0, s1index1);
        String s1part2 = s1.substring(s1index1 + 1, s1.lastIndexOf("."));
        String s1part3 = s1.substring(s1.lastIndexOf(".") + 1);

        int s2index1 = s2.indexOf(".");
        String s2part1 = s2.substring(0, s2index1);
        String s2part2 = s2.substring(s2index1 + 1, s2.lastIndexOf("."));
        String s2part3 = s2.substring(s2.lastIndexOf(".") + 1);

        compVal = Integer.compare(Integer.parseInt(s1part1), Integer.parseInt(s2part1));
        if (compVal == 0) {
            compVal = Integer.compare(Integer.parseInt(s1part2), Integer.parseInt(s2part2));
            if (compVal == 0) {
                compVal = Integer.compare(Integer.parseInt(s1part3), Integer.parseInt(s2part3));
            }
        }
        return compVal;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to interpret the strings as numbers and compare these. If your strings follow this pattern - strings of digits separated by periods - you could do this cheaply using something like this:

```
int num1 = Integer.parseInt(version1.replace(".", ""));
int num2 = Integer.parseInt(version2.replace(".", ""));
if(num2 >= num1) {...}
```